# Mongodb Read preferences

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

SETUP:

I have one PRIMARY and two SECONDARY instances of mongodb.
One of the two secondary instances is hosted in the same region as my web app.

I am using pymongo for connecting.

QUERY:

How can I get connection to a SECONDARY with lower latency.

Currently I am doing this:

```
  from pymongo import ReplicaSetConnection
  from pymongo import ReadPreference

  db = ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017', replicaSet='rs1')['my_db']
  db.read_preference = ReadPreference.SECONDARY
```

I get a connection to any one of the SECONDARY.
How can I force to get connection from the instance with lower latency

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is very specific to my situation, because my nearest secondary is in the same region as my web server (as good as running on the same machine), so the data transfer would be insanely fast, plus I don't have to pay for bandwidth usage (which over the month might become significant considering the amount of data).

Otherwise the default value for 'secondary_acceptable_latency_ms' = 15ms. So it doesn't really matter.

So in case someone finds himself/herself in the same situation, this is what to do:

```
    from pymongo import ReplicaSetConnection
    from pymongo import ReadPreference

    db = ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017', replicaSet='rs1')['my_db']
    db.read_preference = ReadPreference.SECONDARY
    db.secondary_acceptable_latency_ms = 0.001
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

The read preferences are as follows:

- **PRIMARY**: Queries are sent to the primary of the replica set.
- **PRIMARY_PREFERRED**: Queries are sent to the primary if available, otherwise a secondary.
- **SECONDARY**: Queries are distributed among secondaries. An error is raised if no secondaries are available.
- **SECONDARY_PREFERRED**: Queries are distributed among secondaries, or the primary if no secondary is available.
- **NEAREST**: Queries are distributed among all members.

So theres **no** specific one for the *nearest* secondary.  You could achieve this by combining NEAREST and [tag_sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#tag-setshat) and tagging the secondaries.

Then if the secondaries have been tagged `{'secondaries': 1}` you can read from the nearest secondary like so:

```
from pymongo import ReplicaSetConnection
from pymongo import ReadPreference

db = ReplicaSetConnection('localhost:27017', replicaSet='rs1')['my_db']
db.read_preference = ReadPreference.NEAREST
db.tag_sets = [{'secondaries': 1}]
```

## Update:

You should note that if an election occurs and the topology of your replicaset changes then you'd have to manually change the tag_sets to represent the new secondaries.

Comment: I also found this: "secondary_acceptable_latency_ms". I am thinking of setting this to a lower value (default is 15 ms). So that only the secondary with lower latency time is connected. I will try this and get back.

Comment: And you are right, if I go by the way of tag_sets, changing the tag_sets would be a pain (might forget). I had thought of this earlier. And if I was to use tag_sets, I would rather just assign a tag_set to the SECONDARY I want to use.

Comment: Actually, the driver reads from the nearest secondary, or any secondary w/in 15ms of it, if your read preference is SECONDARY. Same for SECONDARY_PREFERRED, unless only the primary is up, in which case read from primary.

So if you set read preference SECONDARY_PREFERRED and secondary_acceptable_latency_ms to .001 (since zero isn't allowed), you'll only read from the secondary with least latency as measured by the driver.

Comment: (Note also, just in case there's any confusion, that "latency" is the member's ping time from the machine running your application; it's completely distinct from replication lag.)

Comment: Yes I understand that...The main reason why I wanted it connect to the nearest secondary was because the nearest secondary (in my case) is in the same region as my web server. So since I will be dealing with huge amount of data, First it will be faster, Second I will not have to pay for the bandwidth.

Comment: So I guess, using secondary_acceptable_latency_ms would be the best way.